# How to get attribute value from node using xpath?

Tags: xml, string, xpath, return-value

Totally new to xpath.

I have xml:

```
<Values>
   <Value Value="a" CustomAtr="1" />
   <Value Value="b" CustomAtr="2" />
   <Value Value="c" CustomAtr="3" />
</Values>
```

To get value by index, i can use: `string(/*/Value[1]/@CustomAtr)`

Is it possible to get value by key?
Hot to get `CustomAtr` value where `Value="b"` ?

Thank you

Answer (score 43, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
string(//Value[@Value='b']/@CustomAttr)
```